# Link building with backlinks in footer of a website

Tags: seo, backlinks

i don't have experience in SEO and Link building.

The thing is that my website has PA and DA 0 and domain is not new, but i have good amount of websites with solid and good PA and DA which you can see on the screen below.

[Backlinks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9t5.png)

and i have around 100 other backlinks with DA & PA 1.

How important are the backlinks to the website authority?

How much will this backlinks affect on my website's DA and PA?

This websites are international, how would they affect my specific local keyword as anchor text?

Thank You very much!

Comment: Sorry but your question is too broad, duplicate and opinionated (one question you asked "how much will these backlinks effect my DA/PA" is unanswerable. Use the search function for [footer links](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Footer+link), [domain authorithy](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=domain+authority+is%3Aquestion) etc. 


If you have a unique specific question that has not been asked in any form already then by all means post another question that is specific, visit our help centre for further advice.

Comment: You should also be aware that 100 backlinks from non relevant websites will likely grant your site with a one way ticket to [Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin) land.

Comment: Thank You very much Simon on answer. Now i got all i wanted. Cheers